# Is there any downside for an employer to place excess true-up contributions above the 401(k) contribution limit in a non qualified account?

Tags: united-states, 401k, true-up

Is there any downside for an employer to place excess true-up contributions above the 401(k) contribution limit ([IRS 415(c)(1)(A)](https://www.standard.com/news/irs-announces-indexed-limits-2017) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180718065420/https://www.standard.com/news/irs-announces-indexed-limits-2017)): 54kUSD in 2017, 55kUSD in 2018)) in a non qualified account, instead of setting a limit on  after-tax 401(k) contributions?

---

This question is about personal finance as it allows us, personal investors, to discuss about it with our 401(k) plan manager if needs be, in case there is the downside doesn't outweight the upside.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81169/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-is-there-any-downside-for-an-employ) and further ones are subject to deletion without being saved in chat. It looked like the existing comments were converging on an answer, I'd suggest just writing them up as one.