# How do should I optimize my 401k employee contribution to maximize my employer's contribution?

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, roth-401k, employer-match

I just want to maximize my employer's contribution.
My current employer plan has the following constraints

> Company will provide a 100% (dollar-for- dollar) match on the first 5%
> of eligible W-2
>
> Compensation you contribute on a before-tax 401(k), after-tax Roth
> 401(k) or after-tax non-Roth basis each pay period, up to the IRS
> compensation limit. Once your compensation reaches this limit, the
> company match must end.
>
> Note: The company match is contributed each pay period. In order to
> receive the maximum company match, you need to contribute a minimum of
> 5% of compensation on a before-tax 401(k), after-tax Roth 401(k) or
> after-tax non-Roth basis each pay period.

Suppose I make 100k salary.
That means at most the company will contribute 5k

The HR department mentioned it was better to spread my 401k contribution rather than doing a lump sum.
I am really confused why that would be the case, when specifically it says 100% match.

Why is it true if I contribute lump sum $5k, it will not be optimized?
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That also confused me a lot when I started working in the US. Turns out that by "match on the first 5% of eligible W-2", many (all?) employers mean 5% of your earned W2 so far, not the entire yearly W2.

Let's assume that you get paid every week with 2kUSD. Many (all?) companies will match only 5% of it, ie 100 USD. However, if you contribute more than 100 USD per paycheck to your 401k, then some ([but not all](https://www.doughroller.net/retirement-planning/should-you-max-out-your-401k-early-in-the-year/#:%7E:text=Without%20the%20match%2C%20front%20loading%20your%20401k%20is%20worth%20considering.&text=There%20is%20an%20annual%20limit,for%20those%2050%20or%20older.)) employers will catch up on the missing match at the end of the year, as year-end true-up contributions, to ensure they do 100% (dollar-for- dollar) match on the first 5% of eligible yearly 100kUSD W-2.

Therefore, when "The HR department mentioned it was better to spread my 401k contribution rather than doing a lump sum", ask them if they do end of year true-up contributions, and if so, why they make such a claim.

---

FYI:

- [Can a year-end true-up employer match exceed the 401(k) maximum contribution, in which case the employee would past of their 401(k) contributions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/97599/5656)
- [Is there any downside for an employer to place excess true-up contributions above the 401(k) contribution limit in a non qualified account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/98242/5656)
- [Does a 401(k) year-end true-up employer match received in year X+1 for year X count toward the 401(k) max contributions for year X or year X + 1?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/97202/5656)
- [Is a year-end true-up employer match supposed to be received the next year?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/96527/5656)

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Would it be optimal then to simply put 5% of your paycheck each week, just to simply get all of the employers contributions and put as little amount to 401k?

Comment: @user I often wonder the same. Let's ask the experts: [Should one max out one's 401(k) at the beginning of the year?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/148939/5656). Personally I frontload it asap at the beginning of the year.

Comment: No it doesn't mean "earned income so far" it means "earned in that particular pay period".  It also says "you need to contribute a minimum of 5% of compensation [] each pay period" which is not possible with a front-load.  Besides that, true-up is less valuable than on-time match for several reasons.